# How to select between Holt Winters Model and ARIMA

Tags: forecasting, arima, model-selection, exponential-smoothing

I need to do sales forecasting.My historical data shows stationary pattern & present of trend,Seasonality & cyclic pattern. I would like to check with you that how to select between Holt Winters and ARIMA to decide the method to be used for future prediction?

Thanks

Comment: The Holt Winter's forecasting method is simple exponential smoothing which is a special case of ARIMA models, namely the IMA(0,1,1) model.

Comment: To be more precise, I would say either ARIMA(0,1,1) or IMA(1,1) since the zero in IMA(0,1,1) indexes the AR order that is excluded from the model name. R Learner, check also earlier threads on the subject; similar questions have been asked before. E.g. [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219279/when-to-use-exponential-smoothing-vs-arima) would be a duplicate, but it does not have a good answer. Hmm, so probably we still need an answer to this one.

Comment: @RichardHardy: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I do not think my comment constitutes an answer to the actual question (about model selection for forecasting). Rather, it is more of a clarification regarding terminology.

Comment: @RichardHardy: I think it's as close as we will get to an answer to this question... I'll post a short answer.

Answer (score 2):

As [Michael Chernick](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261861/how-to-select-between-holt-winters-model-and-arima?noredirect=1#comment501119_261861) and [Richard Hardy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261861/how-to-select-between-holt-winters-model-and-arima?noredirect=1#comment501265_261861) point out, there are relationships between Exponential Smoothing and ARIMA models that essentially mean that the forecasts won't differ by much (differences mainly driven by choices in the initialization).

I would recommend that you run a holdout test and choose the method that performs best on a holdout sample. [This may be helpful.](https://otexts.com/fpp2/accuracy.html)

(See [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) for a motivation for short answers. Longer answers are always welcome.)

Comment: I actually did not (intend to) express a thought that *the forecasts won't differ by much*. Probably they would, given that ARIMA can model a rather rich selection of patterns (unlike HW which is rather specific).

Comment: @RichardHardy: yes, it depends on whether `auto.arima()` (or whatever) actually chooses an ARIMA model that is equivalent to a smoothing one. I still think that there is little to choose between them in terms of forecasting accuracy. To be honest, in sales forecasting, [data cleansing and correct modeling of demand drivers is usually *far* more important than choosing between ARIMA and Smoothing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/355395/1352).

Comment: Given your experience, you certainly know what you are talking about, so no objections.