# Time Series Case Study

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

In time series, to forecast for 6 months, how much past data is sufficient ? I am having  13 years of data in file in which the first 3-4 years data is going down and then data is going up for the last 9 years?

Answer (score 5):

"Sufficient" is a relative term.

I assume that you have monthly data. You can forecast out [from very short series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/135061/1352), even from a single observation (the forecast will then necessarily be a repetition of that observation). One would expect accuracy to increase as history length increases, although of course, accuracy is first of all more *variable* for short series.

Whether the accuracy from a short series is "sufficient" for your purposes, and whether the improvement from more data ([or a deeper understanding of your series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/355395/1352)) is worth the added expense depends on what you plan on using the forecast for.

---

And of course, the relationship of "more data implies higher accuracy" is a bit tenuous. Below, I use a monthly series from the M3 competition and successively fit `auto.arima()` models to the last 1, 2, ... observations. I then plot the RMSE against the length of the history used. In general, the RMSE goes down. (It doesn't necessarily - just look at other series by changing the `ii` to any value between 1402 and 2829, the monthly series.) However, in between there are sharp spikes. I assume (but have not investigated) that these are lengths at which `auto.arima()` switches between seasonal and nonseasonal models. Shooting itself in the foot now and then.

[image: RMSE against history length]

R code:

```
library(forecast)
library(Mcomp)

which(sapply(M3,"[","period")=="MONTHLY")   # indices of MONTHLY series
ii <- 1407  # a MONTHLY series

history_length <- 1:length(M3[[ii]]$x)

acc <- matrix(nrow=length(history_length),ncol=8)
rownames(acc) <- history_length
colnames(acc) <- colnames(accuracy(forecast(auto.arima(tail(M3[[ii]]$x,1)),h=6),M3[[ii]]$xx))

for ( hh in history_length ) {
    acc[hh,] <- accuracy(forecast(auto.arima(tail(M3[[ii]]$x,hh)),h=6),M3[[ii]]$xx)[2,]
}

plot(history_length,acc[,"RMSE"],type="o",pch=19,xlab="History Length",ylab="RMSE")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am working on some assignment, and need the good accuracy model. I know increasing historical data beyond certain point doesn't make sense. But in general, to make model with good accuracy, ideally last 5 years or 7 years is sufficient??

Comment: As I wrote, "good" is relative and subjective. I personally would feel OK about at least three years of data. Assuming there are no demand drivers that need to be modeled.