# Poor results with auto.arima in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality

I have the below time series with 361 daily observations (180 observations for year 1 and 181 for year 2). I created the series like this:
`arrivals <- ts(X, frequency = 180, start = c(2018, 1))`.
[image]

Seasonal decompostion looks like this after `arrivals <- decompose(arrivals)`:
[image]

After `auto <- auto.arima(arrivals, seasonal = T) f <- forecast(auto, h=50)`, I got this forecast:
[image]

Shouldn't the forecast be a little more accurate at least (show hints of seasonality) or
my time series analysis is just that trivial? What can I try to get better results?

Comment: What makes you think your forecast is poor or inaccurate? Anyway, ARIMA has a hard time dealing with long seasonality, so it's good it has already picked a seasonal difference. Have you tried a longer term forecast? That should at least be seasonal. Finally, can you make your data available somewhere?

Comment: I don't know I expected the forecast to follow the pattern from the 2 previous years. Try this link for the data [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z9H3WwbsyZujsUtoklXHDHMIRlhihs-0/view). No matter the value of the h I get the same prediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I `dput()` the data at the bottom in case someone wants to take a look.

ARIMA has a hard time dealing with "long" seasonality, especially if you have only observed two seasonal cycles. ["Forecasting with long seasonal periods" by Rob Hyndman](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) is very enlightening reading.

Note that the parameter `seasonal=TRUE` does not *force* `auto.arima()` to use a seasonal model, it only *allows* it. Use `D=1` to *force* a seasonal model (see [Seasonality not taken account of in `auto.arima()`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/213201/1352)). Here is what happens then:

```
> model_sarima <- auto.arima(arrivals,D=1)
> model_sarima
Series: arrivals 
ARIMA(2,1,1)(0,1,0)[180] 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1
      0.0627  -0.2052  -0.7837
s.e.  0.0895   0.0827   0.0615

sigma^2 estimated as 116.5:  log likelihood=-686.48
AIC=1380.96   AICc=1381.19   BIC=1393.73
> plot(forecast(model_sarima,h=100),las=1)
```

As you see, we now have a quite different (and seasonal) model.

[image: SARIMA]

Now the forecasts definitely look more, ahem, sophisticated. Whether they are more accurate is doubtful. For one, some of the point forecasts are negative, which you presumably do not want. Actually, the vast prediction intervals give a hint that `auto.arima()` does not think this forecast is very useful.

Here is an equally dubious `stlf` forecast:

```
plot(stlf(arrivals,h=100),las=1)
```

[image: STLF]

An alternative would be to fit a smooth bump function to your two years of history, then extrapolate this forward. But whatever you do, before you forecast you should really think about that conspicuous drop at the end of your series, which is also visible in a seasonplot. Is this some fundamental change, and will your time series go back to normal, or not, and when? [That kind of thinking about the drivers of your series can be far more useful than tweaking ARIMA models.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/355395/1352)

```
seasonplot(arrivals,col=1:2,pch=19,las=1)
legend("topright",lwd=1,pch=19,col=1:2,legend=2018:2019)
```

[image: seasonplot]

---

Data:

```
arrivals <- structure(c(18L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 17L, 12L, 9L, 
17L, 14L, 5L, 17L, 21L, 17L, 20L, 10L, 27L, 8L, 14L, 19L, 15L, 
15L, 14L, 22L, 25L, 16L, 19L, 13L, 17L, 40L, 16L, 16L, 30L, 10L, 
17L, 21L, 25L, 30L, 24L, 21L, 25L, 15L, 22L, 16L, 25L, 13L, 36L, 
29L, 32L, 20L, 24L, 25L, 22L, 36L, 19L, 2L, 24L, 22L, 24L, 11L, 
12L, 21L, 17L, 32L, 24L, 27L, 20L, 31L, 26L, 27L, 23L, 27L, 31L, 
18L, 27L, 36L, 23L, 21L, 28L, 27L, 17L, 23L, 20L, 18L, 23L, 27L, 
25L, 20L, 26L, 36L, 31L, 27L, 29L, 21L, 15L, 29L, 22L, 13L, 24L, 
34L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 25L, 24L, 35L, 23L, 18L, 14L, 25L, 13L, 15L, 
21L, 18L, 8L, 7L, 13L, 25L, 10L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 22L, 12L, 
18L, 23L, 30L, 26L, 9L, 25L, 24L, 13L, 18L, 28L, 17L, 9L, 22L, 
30L, 31L, 37L, 36L, 18L, 10L, 9L, 24L, 36L, 36L, 28L, 5L, 13L, 
30L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 26L, 26L, 4L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 16L, 2L, 4L, 
9L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 13L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 
10L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 26L, 3L, 2L, 18L, 4L, 20L, 29L, 41L, 14L, 
14L, 32L, 30L, 20L, 18L, 33L, 8L, 10L, 22L, 29L, 23L, 28L, 36L, 
12L, 13L, 17L, 10L, 5L, 16L, 33L, 12L, 10L, 17L, 27L, 20L, 26L, 
32L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 17L, 14L, 3L, 30L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 
6L, 15L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 15L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 8L, 8L, 33L, 27L, 12L, 
1L, 19L, 14L, 11L, 28L, 24L, 32L, 30L, 12L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 26L, 
7L, 4L, 7L, 15L, 13L, 20L, 20L, 7L, 15L, 7L, 11L, 16L, 24L, 11L, 
26L, 27L, 17L, 17L, 22L, 13L, 9L, 21L, 20L, 23L, 25L, 23L, 28L, 
22L, 11L, 18L, 20L, 13L, 17L, 26L, 24L, 10L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 
9L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 19L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 
8L, 3L, 12L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 
5L, 2L, 12L, 0L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Tsp = c(2018, 
2020, 180), class = "ts")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe indeed the data are not sufficient for creating a decent SARIMA model. I had never heard about stacking models before, seems like a quite interesting technique.