Stacking for very high imbalanced class problem
Background: I'm facing a 1 : 40 000 class imbalanced problem.
It's a binary classification problem with positive class around ~500-700 instances and negative class in the tens of millions instances.
I have read several other questions, references, etc.:
Binary classification with strongly unbalanced classes
https://machinelearningmastery.com/tour-of-evaluation-metrics-for-imbalanced-classification/
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/61733/class-imbalance-and-cost-sensitive-learning-xgboost
What is the root cause of the class imbalance problem?
and others etc...
Several things I have tried based on those references (and many more):

Under/over-sampling:
I undersampled the data to 10:1 and the performance improved from 0.1% precision to ~1-5% (for highly imbalanced problem, that's quite good in terms of absolute numbers, especially since my data is in the tens of millions). Recall went up from 0.1% to ~5-10% as well.

Tweaking with several hyperparameters generally adjusted for class imbalances:
In most learning algorithms (XGB, CatBoost, LGBM), adjusting scale_pos_weight, min_child_weight, max_delta_step were especially "great" (however, result is still as above).

Tweaking with objective function:
Using cost-sensitive functions such as logloss and AUC

Feature engineering and selection:
33 base/raw features, engineered to 142. From top 10 features, only 2 of the base features have high SHAP values (see: https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/plots/bar.html).

Further feature selection:
I also used VarianceThreshold and tree-based feature selection based on scikit-learn's guide (https://scikit-learn.org/1.5/modules/feature_selection.html)

Stacking:
I built hundreds of base learners in XGBoost, each trained with different hyperparameters (basically, using numpy.random to tweak these around some sensible values), and with different sets of negative classes (i.e. undersampling the majority class with different seeds on each training round), and with different sets of training features (i.e. selecting a random number of features out of my 142 features, although I always keep top 8 features based on SHAP). I then averages out each of these learner's predict_proba, and set a final probability threshold at 99.9%.


Now, the best model (after I combine ALL the methods above) performs at 20-30% recall with 5-10% precision. The target is 50% recall with 50-90% precision.
The next thing I want to try is the following:
Using the hundreds of learners I trained from point 6 (keeping in mind points 1-5 while training each base learners), I'll apply model.predict_proba on my training set.
And then, I'll use that value of predict_proba (from hundreds of base learners) as features to train a final model, on the same training set. The idea is, instead of averaging all the predict_proba of the base learners (same weightage), I'll let a final model decide the weightage of each base learner.
I would like to ask around, if the above idea makes sense?

Will there be data leakage concerns? (because I trained each base learner on my train_set. And then asked it to predict the same train_set. And then use this output to train a final model, also on the train_set).

Do you think, it would also makes sense if I train, say, 100 CatBoost, 100 XGBoost, and 100 LGBM, and then train a neural network based on the total 300 predict_proba outputs? I have read that some model-stacking architectures did this, but I'm not sure if that is a widely-used practice?


Thanks!

Sensitivity, specificity, precision, recall etc. and any weighted combinations of these suffer from all the same issues as accuracy, i.e., they all presume a very specific cost structure to decisions in the face of uncertainty - but they do not make the costs explicit. They are especially problematic in "unbalanced" cases.

Better to work with probabilistic classifications and separate the decision aspect from them. Decisions need to take classifications and costs into account, and even if there are only two classes, there may well be more than two possible decisions

Unbalanced classes are almost certainly not a problem, and oversampling, undersampling or weighting will not solve this non-problem:
Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?
And this Meta.CV thread contains a curated list of useful links on imbalanced data.

"The target is 50% recall with 50-90% precision." Is there any grounds to assume this target is realistic or achievable? Take a look at How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?

Hi @StephanKolassa ; yes I'm aware of the first and second points; that's the reason why I've been using predict_proba and adjusting it as well; for a given positive instance, "0.85" prediction should be better-'rewarded' than "0.6" predictions. But real-life scenarios demand that we make a decision; "Should I or should I not do a certain action". You cannot say "Oh, I will 30% press this button"; you either press a button, or you don't.

@StephanKolassa Yes, I'm aware of the 3rd point as well; several references I attached above have mentioned it as well! Under/over-sampling is generally not really a 'good-practice'. In fact, it's not even a 'problem' at all (as you've mentioned!). Most 'imbalanced data' problem arises due to bad definition of "performance" (e.g. using accuracy as performance metric) or bad definition of objective functions (e.g. using loss functions which are not cost-sensitive). However, I still tried it anyway, and since it helped improved the performance somewhat, I left it in my code!

I suppose, I'm asking the general practitioners out there; were my ideas sensible? I mean, does it make sense to do the stacking that I mentioned? Or would there be concerns regarding that process (and all the other process I did before it)? Unfortunately, I cannot really tweak the 50% recall-90% precision target; it's sort of imposed as a target. However, I'm open if anyone can give some feedback and/or pointers on "how to communicate an impossible problem"? If possible, something that is hard-evidence (e.g. "Based on this approach, theoretically we can't exceed X% precision", for example)

Yes, I only posted comments and not answers because I am quite aware I am not addressing your actual question. I would still encourage you (and your clients) to try looking at matters from a different angle than the precision/recall one. Per my last link, it is very hard to say with any certainty that we have truly reached the end of the flagpole in terms of predictive performance, unless we are trying to forecast the toss of a fair coin. This is one of the main challenges and frustrations of any data scientist. Here is yet one more link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/355395/1352

I am continually saddened to see researchers start a project on the wrong foot.  Classification is only appropriate when needing to make quick forced-choice decisions when the proportion of positive outcomes is near 0.5.  Otherwise one should model tendencies, i.e., probabilities.  See this.  Would you ever say to someone that it’s OK to carry a large metal object on a golf course in an electrical storm because we classify you as not getting hit by lightning?

It looks to me that you are likely heading towards over-fitting in model selection/degrees of researcher freedom where you may be overfitting the test data by making lots of manual choices about the model.  As others have pointed out, you need to determine what performance criterion is relevant to your application, and in particular false-positive and false-negative costs.  I disagree with Frank Harrell above, it may be that classification is the requirement for your application, in which case you do need to consider a performance criterion that depends on the classification threshold, ...

... as well as performance metrics that measure other relevant aspects of performance, e.g. quality of tendencies/probabilities.
